# How to find last 7 days date in python in ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have wanted to know how can I get the date of last  days in ISO 8601 in python please help me i don't have any idea on this

Comment: 1- forget the format, Format is just for input and output. Check `datetime` module (Python has a very good documentation). You have also a class about time differences, you just check 7 days before your datum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
for i in range(7):
    day = today - timedelta(days=i)
    iso = day.isoformat()
    print(f"{i} days ago: {iso}")
```

Prints the following:

```
0 days ago: 2020-08-20
1 days ago: 2020-08-19
2 days ago: 2020-08-18
3 days ago: 2020-08-17
4 days ago: 2020-08-16
5 days ago: 2020-08-15
6 days ago: 2020-08-14
```

You can use `datetime.datetime` instead of `datetime.date` if you also want time information. Feel free to [look through the `datetime` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and experiment with it.

The `isoformat()` method of `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` will always format in ISO 8601. You can use `strftime()` to output in any other format, if you want.

Comment: (Ever so) slightly more efficient: instead of repeatedly creating a new `timedelta` instance to subtract from `today`, just keep subtracting `day -= timedelta(days=1)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accumulate`.

```
from itertools import accumulate, repeat
from datetime import timedelta, date
```

In Python 3.8, you can write

```
one_day = timedelta(days=1)
last_seven_days = accumulate(repeat(one_day, 7), sub, initial=date.today())
for d in last_seven_days:
    print(d)
```

Prior to 3.8, you need to include today's date at the head of the sequence of `timedelta`s, which is a little messier to write. (Python has no convenient way to prepend a single item onto the beginning of an iterator.)

```
last_seven_days = accumulate([date.today()] + list(repeat(one_day, 7)), sub)
```